# Wordpress Backend HA (Automatic failover)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, database, mysql, backup

Out setup is multiple Front Ends (replicated) and 2 Backend MYSQL servers (Master-Master replication).

We're looking to achieve HA automatic failover for wordpress. We've got the front ends covered through replication and a load balancer.

Any ideas on how to achieve **AUTOMATIC** MySQL failover?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve automatic failover using a synchronous service, like [Galera cluster](http://galeracluster.com/).

It requires three nodes, but you can set up two nodes there, along with an arbitrator.

Answer (score 0):

We use [MariaDB Galera Replication](https://jelastic.com/blog/mariadb-galera-cluster-replication/) for ensuring high availability of our [WordPress Enterprise](https://jelastic.com/wordpress-enterprise-services/) solution. Load balancing and automatic failover can be achieved with a help of DNS round robin (assigning multiple IP addresses of database instances to one hostname) or with a help of ProxySQL (or MaxScale) placed in front of database cluster.